Can I get the logging statements from my C++ app into Visual Studio?
I have a desktop application I'm working on, but the issue is that when I try to use cout to log whatever, it doesn't show up in Visual Studio.
So I tried running my app through the command prompt because I saw somewhere that worked, but it also didn't.
I was wondering if I could get the logging statements directly to Visual Studio, or am I going to have to save my log messages to a file/use a logging library?

See OutputDebugString - "Sends a string to the debugger for display".

Possible duplicate: Simplest way to write output message to Output Window In Visual Studio.

If you go the OutputDebugString route and want to view it without the debugger, like a machine without Visual Studio installed, you might find https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview handy.

"I have a desktop application I'm working on, but the issue is that when I try to use cout to log whatever, it doesn't show up in Visual Studio.". Show us the code please.

Personally I find the output windows to be a bit messy so I usually log to a file and use https://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/ to view it. Handy to be able to color different levels so they're more obvious.

Side note from years of pain: Stuff that you think is important enough to print out is important enough to write to a log file. Too many times the important message has been pushed off the top of the screen or otherwise out of the display's buffer by the time you get to look at it. By all means dump it to the console, when you can, for immediate feedback, but dump it to a log file as well.

cout writes to a console terminal. But by default, a GUI app doesn't have a console assigned to it (even when run from a command prompt). So, that's likely why you aren't seeing your messages anywhere.  Log the message to your app's UI instead, like in a multi-line EDIT control, or a LISTBOX, or a LITVIEW, etc.
If you really want to see the messages externally, using OutputDebugString() is one option. You will see the messages only when you are running your app inside of a debugger, or if you use a tool like SysInternals DebugView.
Otherwise, just write your messages to a file, or put them in a database, etc.
